# Using ManagementClass.Getinstances() from IronPython

Tags: python, wmi, ironpython

I have an IronPython script that looks for current running processes using WMI. The code looks like this:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Management')
from System.Management import ManagementClass
from System import Array
mc = ManagementClass('Win32_Processes')
procs = mc.GetInstances()
```

That last line where I call the `GetInstances()` method raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call first):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: Not Found
```

I am not understanding what's not being found?!? I believe that I may need to pass an instance of `ManagementOperationObserver` and of `EnumerationOptions` to `GetInstance()` however, I don't understand why that is, since the method with the signature `Getinstance()` is available in `ManagementClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only problem is that 'Win32_Processes' is a typo for **'Win32_Process'**.  This seems to work:

```
>>> mc = ManagementClass('Win32_Process')
>>> procs = mc.GetInstances()
>>> for p in procs:
...     print p['Name']
... 
System Idle Process
System
smss.exe
(etc)
```